# Gibt es einen Oberbegriff für "Verkauf" und "Leihstellung"?

Tags: single-word-request

Es gibt die Begriffe "Überlassung" und "Veräußerung". Aber damit sind immer Vorgänge gemeint, bei denen der Besitz an den Empfänger übergeht. Ich suche einen Begriff der die örtliche Veränderung einer Sache von Person A zu Person B beschreibt, ohne aber eine Aussage über die Besitzverhältnisse zu machen. Gibt es so einen Begriff?

Comment: *Besitz* bedeutet im deutschen Recht die tatsächliche Herrschaft über eine Sache. Wenn eine Sache an eine Person übergeht, hat diese Person anschließend die Herrschaft über die Sache Ausgenommen sind vielleicht Sonderfälle, in denen sich die Sache in einem verschlossenen Behälter befindet, für die die Person keinen Schlüssel hat. Generell geht mit der Ortsveränderung aber auch einher, dass die Zielperson die Herrschaft über die Sache erhält. Damit geht nach meinem Verständnis auch der Besitz über.

Comment: Die Frage ist ein bisschen schwierig zu beantworten, weil sie einen Unterschied zwischen juristischem und allgemeinem Sprachgebrauch im Deutschen offenlegt. Der Jurist versteht unter *Besitz* etwas anderes als unter *Eigentum* (ein Ding "haben" vs. "alle Rechte daran haben", oder *possession* vs. *ownership*), im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch ist es dasselbe. Deine Frage scheint eher im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch gestellt? Ist dein Umfeld also *juristischer* oder *allgemeiner* Sprachgebrauch?

Comment: Was spricht gegen *geben*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich stimme der Annahme nicht zu, dass *Überlassung* einen Eigentumsübergang darstellen muss und zwar weder juristisch noch umgangssprachlich (wie in *Kannst du mir für das Wochenende dein Auto überlassen?*.

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/%C3%9Cberlassung) gibt als Bedeutung u. a. an:

> Bereitstellen von etw. zur Nutzung durch jmd. anderen

Wikipedia zu [Miete](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miete) schreibt u. a.:

> Immobiliarmiete, die entgeltliche Überlassung von Räumen und Grundstücken

Deswegen ist für mich *Überlassung* nach wie vor korrekt. Alternativen sind [Zurverfügungstellung](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Zurverfuegungstellung) oder etwas einfacher *Bereitstellung*

Comment: Die Umgangssprache versteht unter Besitzübergang und Eigentumsübergang dasselbe - Der Jurist nicht. Aus "Mein Opa hat mir sein Auto überlassen" geht (für mich, und ich bin kein Jurist) keinesfalls hervor, ob es mir jetzt gehört oder nicht. - Der Wikipedia-Eintrag verwendet ziemlich eindeutig juristischen Sprachgebrauch.

Comment: DWDS selber ist schon uneindeutig: "dauerhafte, leihweise, zeitweise Überlassung". Und bei einer Arbeitnehmerüberlassung wechselt der Arbeitnehmer auch nicht seinen Besitzer, obwohl viele das vielleicht gerne so hätten. Somit scheint mir der Begriff jetzt auch hinreichend schwammig, so dass ich auch nicht mehr denke, dass der Begriff zwangsläufig eine Eigentumsänderung impliziert.

Answer (score 2):

Ich bin zwar kein Jurist, aber Besitzer (und Eigentümer) eines kommentierten [ABGB](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allgemeines_b%C3%BCrgerliches_Gesetzbuch) -- das folgende bezieht sich also auf österreichisches Recht.

Zunächst: Besitz heißt Innehabung + Besitzwillen:

> § 309. Wer eine Sache in seiner Macht oder Gewahrsame hat, heißt ihr Inhaber. Hat der Inhaber einer Sache den Willen, sie als die seinige zu behalten, so ist er ihr Besitzer.

Dazu steht in den Kommenaren:

> An einer einmal begründeten Sachinnehabung iS des § 309 ändert sich durch die *Weitergabe des Objekts* jedenfalls dann nichts, wenn die Gewahrsame, also der Herrschaftsbereich des Übergebers, erhalten bleibt, der vom bisher unmittelbaren Inhaber nur zum mittelbaren wurde (...).
>
> Die **Macht** *über* eine *Sache* kann auch *durch* einen *Dritten an* einem *andern Ort* ausgeübt werden, zB Sparbücher und Sparbriefe, die einem Dritten zur Aufbewahrung bei einer Bank übergeben worden sind (...).

(Dittrich/Tades, ABGB, 2011; Hervorhebungen im Original).

Damit ist scheinbar der von dir gemeinte Betriff im österreichischen Besitzrecht die *Weitergabe*, wobei selbst Juristen auch *Übergabe* benutzen.  Allerdings scheint es, dass du mit "Besitz" eigentlich "Eigentum" meinst, oder die deutschländischen Begrifflichkeiten sind anders.

Das Gegenstück (oder eigentlich Gegenteil) dazu im Eigentumsrecht ist die *Übergabe*, eine der mehreren offiziellen Möglichkeiten des Eigentumserwerbs; siehe dazu das "fünfte Hauptstück, von Erwerbung des Eigentumes durch Übergabe":

> § 425. Der bloße Titel gibt noch kein Eigentum. Das Eigentum und alle dinglichen Rechte überhaupt können, außer den in dem Gesetze bestimmten Fällen, nur durch die rechtliche Übergabe und Übernahme erworben werden.

Worunter bei beweglichen Sachen die *körperliche Übergabe* (§ 426) "von Hand zu Hand" fällt; aber Kommentar dazu:

> "Körperliche Übergabe" setzt **unmittelbare Besitzübertragung** mit dem *Willen*, Eigentum zu geben und zu übernehmen, voraus (...).

Ansonsten können bewegliche Sachen durch "Zeichen" oder "Erklärung" übergeben werden, also laienhaft: schriftlich oder durch sonstige eindeutige Willensbekundung.

Die *Überlassung* ist dagegen, soweit ich verstehe, nur eine spezielle Form der Ausübung von Besitz, nämlich die Übertragung desselben (oder zumindest der Innehabung).  Er kommt im ABGB, laut meinem Index zumindest, nicht in relevanter Weise vor.

Comment: Auch diese Antwort antwortet leider mit der Sprache der Juristen - Der allgemeine Sprachgebrauch ist allerdings ein anderer.